# Blender 2.8 UV unwrapped regular shelves shows triangluar faces instead of squares?

Tags: uv

[image]

As you see in the picture, the faces of shelves are shown as triangle faces w/ 4 vertices.

What did I do wrong in modeling phase?
How can I avoid this mistake in the future?
Is there a way to fix it instead of manually moving the vertices?

Thank you.

Comment: i just did 'Smart UV Project' and it made everything fine ha. but any input will be appreciated.

Comment: Hard to tell at the current resolution, but you probably missed at least one UV seam.  Try to think about seam placement like making a paper cut out model. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y7M-B6xnaEM